# Using NSArray and NSDictionary: Can not convert value of type "string" to expected argument type "int"

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning using the external database which i use mysql+ php. The data structure is very simple. I only have 1 table "post" with 4 attributes: id, title, author and content.  Then I tried to learn from the online video

If I copied the exact code, it could build successfully, later it came the error message

> "Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x882178) to
>   'NSDictionary' (0x882394)."

at the coding of

```
let response = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary".
```

So I changed the  `NSDictionary` to `NSArray` in the  coding, then it comes out another error in the another coding and even could not build successfully.

> "can not convert value of type of 'String" to expected argument "int"

at the coding of

```
self.loadPosts(response["posts"] as! NSArray)
```

Now I don't what to do and please help.

These are the coding for the post `service.swift`

```
import Foundation

class PostService {
   var settings:Settings

   init () {
   self.settings = Settings()

   }

   func getPosts(callback:(NSArray) -> () ){

        request(settings.viewPosts, callback: callback)
   }

    func request(url:String, callback:(NSArray) -> ()){

        let nsURL = NSURL(string: url)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL!)
            {(data,response,error) in

                let _: NSError

                let response = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
                callback (response)
         }

        task.resume()
      }
}
```

The following code is in `masterviewcontroller.swift`:

```
var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var postsCollection = [Post]()
var service:PostService!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "insertNewObject:")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    if let split = self.splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
    }
    service = PostService()
    service.getPosts{
        (response) in
        self.loadPosts(response["posts"] as! NSArray)
    }


}

// func loadPosts
func loadPosts (posts:NSArray){

    for post in posts {
        let id = post["Post"]!!["id"] as! String
        let title = post["Post"]!!["title"] as! String
        let author = post["Post"]!!["author"] as! String
        let content = post["Post"]!!["content"] as! String
        let postObj = Post(id: id, title: title, author: author, content: content)
        postsCollection.append(postObj)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution.
I just changed self.loadPosts(response["posts"] as NSArray) to the following and it works.

self.loadPosts(response )